# Checking for unique elements in a string vs. converting string to a set

Tags: python, string, set

I've seen the below "code1" used for checking for most frequently used characters in a string where each character is first checked for uniqueness rather than simply converting the string to a set (as in "code2"). Is the "code1" method preferred due to the slight performance improvement? And why is converting a string to a set more expensive than checking each element of the string if it already exists in a dictionary?

code1=

```
string = "This is an example string"
char_list = {}
for char in string:
    if char in char_list:
        char_list[char] += 1
    else:
        char_list[char] = 1

max_frequency = max(char_list.values())
chars_with_max_frequency = [key for key, value in char_list.items() if value == max_frequency]
```

code2=

```
string = "This is an example string"
char_list = {}
for char in set(string):
    char_list[char] = string.count(char)

max_frequency = max(char_list.values())
chars_with_max_frequency = [key for key, value in char_list.items() if value == max_frequency]
```

print("Method #1: Checking string for unique chars: %.4f" % timeit.timeit(code1,number=1000000))

print("Method #2: Converting string to set: %.4f" % timeit.timeit(code2,number=1000000))

---

Method #1: Checking string for unique chars: 2.6955

Method #2: Converting string to set: 3.4223

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first method (`code1`), you are iterating through each character in the string and incrementing a counter for that character in a dictionary. The operation is `O(n)` because each character is being visited exactly once, where `n` is the length of the string.

In the second method (`code2`), after converting the string to a set (which eliminates duplicates and is an `O(n)` operation), you're invoking the `string.count(char)` method. This method itself is an `O(n)` operation because it needs to traverse the entire string to count occurrences of the character. As this is done for each unique character, the total operation becomes `O(n^2)`. In the worst-case scenario, this could be as large as the length of the string itself.

So, to conclude, the conversion of the string to a set is not the expensive operation here. Instead, the expensive operation in the second method is the repeated use of the `string.count()` function. This is why the first method is faster than the second one.

Answer (score 1):

in code 1 you are just checking the uniqueness of the elements and then incrementing a count. This require traversing through the string only once which has a time complexity of O(n) where n is the number of elements in the string.

but in code 2 you have to have to first convert string to a set and then count the number of elements. This will have a time complexity of O(n) * O(n) since we need to travel across the string once to convert it and then again traverse through it to count so it will give a time complexity of O(n^2).

Time complexity of O(n) is much better than O(n^2) so the first method is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions about both of your techniques have already been answered, so I'll add a third option [leveraging the stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count characters in a string :

```py
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter('AABBCCDDAAADD')
sorted_keys = sorted(counts.items(), 
                     key=lambda x:x[1], 
                     reverse=True)

print(sorted_keys) 
# prints [('A', 5), ('D', 4), ('B', 2), ('C', 2)]
```

This will be two operations :

- O(n) on your inital strings, where n=strlen
- and O(nlogn) where n is the count of distinct characters in your string, which should be reasonnably small (unless you're working on some very diverse UTF-8 data)